# How To Migrate From maven-bundle-plugin 2.5.3 to 3.0.0

Tags: maven, apache-felix

My maven *pom.xml* has a dependency to the `maven-bundle-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version> 
</plugin>
```

There are already a couple of releases for version 3, but there is [no documentation](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) on what the API break was that made them increase the major version.

After hours of digging I found the [documentation for the sprint](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX/fixforversion/12332363/), but I have no way to know for sure which of the issues was the API break (my guess would be [FELIX-5047](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-5047), but that's purely speculative).

What do I need to migrate my projects from 2.5.3 to 3.0.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You only need to change the version in your POM file.**

About the version change, from the [changelog.txt](https://github.com/apache/felix/blob/240ab5241a78de32f8f34c8231c97d4565800475/doc/changelog.txt):

> Changes from 2.5.5 to 3.0.0
>
> ---
>
> ** Improvement
>
> ```
>  * [FELIX-5047] - Disable bnd ScrPlugin by default
>  * [FELIX-5030] - Do not require a pom.xml when Polyglot Maven is used
>  * [FELIX-5029] - Update to bnd 3.0.0
> ```

Most likely, to align with the **bnd** version.